# codeigniter facebook

Tags: facebook, codeigniter

SORRY FOR THE LONG POST. I JUST WANT TO BE CLEAR!! :cheese:

I am using the stated template library in my ci setup and everything works great except for when i use Mr. Haughin's facebook_connect!
facebook_connect works beautifully if I call anything in a separate view file in my controller like so:

```
    function facebookconnect()
{
  $this->load->library('facebook_connect');
    $data = array(
        'user'        => $this->facebook_connect->user,
        'user_id'    => $this->facebook_connect->user_id
        );


  $this->template->write_view('content','fbtest',$data);
  $this->template->render();
}
```

this works no problem calling it from it's own page and everyone is happy. But when I try to put my facebook interactivity into a div on my homepage with this code:

```
function index()
{
    $this->load->library('facebook_connect');

    $data = array(
        'user' => $this->facebook_connect->user,
        'user_id' => $this->facebook_connect->user_id
        );
    $this->template->write_view('content','indexpage',$data);
    $this->template->render();
}
```

My homepage loads fine but I have this error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
```

Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined variable: user_id
Filename: views/indexpage.php
Line Number: 32

This i think is strange as it works with code above. My variables are passed so I don't get it. 
What I want to achieve is that on the homepage a list of facebook friends should appear when page loads. Is there anything i should know about this library? I went through the userguide looking for to see if i could write a separate view to the div that should carry the facebook connect results. Here is my view code just incase it will help:

php if ( !$user_id ): 

php else: 
" />
Hi php$user['first_name']!
(Logout)
php endif;        
    Here's some comments!
    
[removed]
    FB.init("$this->config->item('facebook_api_key')", "/xd_receiver.htm");
[removed]

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be in this line:

```
user_id' => $this->facebook_connect->user_id
```

because facebook's PHP client doesn't have any `user_id` property. The user id is available from:

```
user_id' => $this->facebook_connect->user
```

So try removing the line:

```
'user_id' => $this->facebook_connect->user_id
```

Comment: hey sac,

sorry but it did not work, tried taking the line out and still nothing. thanks for trying anyways.